# Как с помощью ajax получить данные с public API Facebook по заданному адресу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как с помощью ajax получить данные с public API Facebook по заданному адресу?

С чего начинать, что почитать?

Comment: Для начала почитать [документацию](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

описание API Facebook

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Руководство по REST API

> http://www.restapitutorial.ru/lessons/whatisrest.html#code-on-demand

не знаю что еще по данному вопросу можно добавить